# Date compare in validation rule

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, datetime

This might be a very easy question but I just wanted to make myself clear on it.

This is to be done in a validation rule formula. Say the date time field is Test__c

1) I need to compare a date time field value if it is greater than Yesterday.

2) Compare a date time field value if greater than a specific date.

3) greater than LAST_N_DAYS: 2 (What this actually mean? Day before yesterday or a day even before that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check

Test__c = **Now**() - 2

OR

Test__c = **Now**() - 3

The number has to be subtracted from Now() function. Validation rule will fire when it will return **TRUE**.

Comment: For point 1 which answer would be correct?

Comment: Datevalue(Test__c) > Today() - 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `DATEVALUE(datetime field)` function to extract the date part from the date/time field and then compare it with values like `TODAY() - 1` or any specific date value ... you can use `DATE(year, month, day)` function to build a static date to compare..

refer this [salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=0) for sample date & datetime formulas